# javascript custom event bind delegation like jQuery.on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to imitate `jQuery.on("click", ".target", handler)` by utilizing `addEventListener()` method. My research on Stackoverflow end up with this: [Native addEventListener with selector like .on() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174056/native-addeventlistener-with-selector-like-on-in-jquery).

**So, before some one mark my question as DUPLICATE  please read carefully my requirements and my demo**.

Here is my Plunker demo https://plnkr.co/edit/so8Sur?p=preview ( I am running chrome when testing it ). Following is the explanation for it:

- At purple box which is "jQuery way" is running as my expectation which should be show Message popup no matter i am clicking on `.target` box or it children which is `.target-child`.
- But for green box which is my custom event binding, with custom function: `customOn(selector, type, filter, handler)`, it will only show popup when click on `.target` box only, but it will not show popup when i click on `.target-child`.

So, my question is, I wonder what kind of magic used by jQuery to make event to be triggered when click on the `.target-child` on my demo, while the actual selector filter is `.target`. Will jQuery traverse up on DOM trees to check any selector match every time it needs to handle delegated event? If yes, i feel it will take enough computation resource ( maybe RAM ), is that right? I hope there will be much efficient way rather than doing traverse up like that.

Any answer and comment will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no magic at all, it just uses event bubbling. Your logic seems very overcomplicated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for your comment. Actually i am not really good about event bubbling knowledge. If you could give me an answer to imitate jQuery way by using those event bubbling, that would be great.

Comment: That answer is in the duplicate you linked to.

Comment: As i remember i have tried that and the result is also unexpected, here is demo based on my understanding on those Stackoverflow i linked to: https://plnkr.co/edit/2eWO61?p=preview . If you click on "child of target" box, it will do nothing ( expect to show popup ) like on the "jQuery way"

Answer (score -3):

Jquery use css selectors as crawling system.
So if you click on something, it will "crawl" the parents until it match (or not) the target.

Comment: This behaviour, known as 'event bubbling' not 'crawling', firstly has nothing to do with selectors, and secondly is not jQuery specific. It's a JS construct.

Comment: Nice downvote, thanks. It does perform a crawl, that is exactly what bubbling is. and it's all about selectors and jquery since @bayu ask about how jquery trigger events on objects that are childs of another and the jquery syntax uses css selector to let the dev select an object by is classname. that was a simple answer, easy to understand for the op.. nevermind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i still can't find official documentation which match your answer, about how those CSS "crawl" things related with event delegation by using jQuery `on()` method.

Comment: If you need doc about it, as @RoryMcCrossan said, you have to search for "javascript bubbling". I used the term "crawl" to picture what happens insight