# How to seprate 2 event for 2 child on a parent element in HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make 2 function select and delete, but something wrong happen when I click select it triggers function delete and I see the value NaN on the console. How can I fix that problem?

```js
        var collect = document.getElementById('collect');
        collect.addEventListener('change', onChange);
        collect.addEventListener('click', onDelete);
        
        function onChange(event) {
            var changeButton = event.target;
            i = parseInt(changeButton.dataset.select);
            console.log(i);
        }

        function onDelete(event) {
            var deleteButton = event.target;
            i = parseInt(deleteButton.dataset.delete);
            console.log(i); 
        }
```

```css
.card {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="collect">
        <div class="card">
            <button data-delete='1'>Delete</button>
            CARD 1
            <select name="" id="" data-select='1'>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <button data-delete='2'>Delete</button>
            CARD 2
            <select name="" id="" data-select='2'>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <button data-delete='3'>Delete</button>
            CARD 3
            <select name="" id="" data-select='3'>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Additional,
Second question: I still don't know the best way to delete the card. I did used jquery      `$("button[data-delete='" + i + "']").parents('.card').remove();`. But it's seem not good:(. Could you help me?

Comment: Did  you  try this  with  jquery?

Comment: I am newbie, I just know a little function of jquery, could you have any suggest?

Comment: @KenHoàng What you wrote almost makes sense, however start with what you want to achieve and then what you did. It's hard to help you when we dont know the goal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A click on select control fires the `click` event and runs `onDelete` handler (because it listens `click` event). So, you need to prevent handling clicks on select control within `onDelete` handler. It may be implemented by checking type of a clicked element using [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) property.

To remove a card you could use solution from the [How to remove the parent element using plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727717/how-to-remove-the-parent-element-using-plain-javascript) topic. So, the result code will be as following.

```js
var collect = document.getElementById('collect');
collect.addEventListener('change', onChange);
collect.addEventListener('click', onDelete);

function onChange(event) {
  var changeButton = event.target;
  if (changeButton.nodeName !== 'SELECT')
    return false;
  i = parseInt(changeButton.dataset.select);
  console.log(i);
}

function onDelete(event) {
  var deleteButton = event.target;
  if (deleteButton.nodeName !== 'BUTTON')
    return false;
  i = parseInt(deleteButton.dataset.delete);
  console.log(i);
  deleteButton.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(deleteButton.parentNode);
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="collect">
  <div class="card">
    <button data-delete='1'>Delete</button> CARD 1
    <select name="" id="" data-select='1'>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <button data-delete='2'>Delete</button> CARD 2
    <select name="" id="" data-select='2'>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <button data-delete='3'>Delete</button> CARD 3
    <select name="" id="" data-select='3'>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also it is possible to separate event sources using classes and solution from the [Native addEventListener with selector like .on() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174056/native-addeventlistener-with-selector-like-on-in-jquery) topic.

Good luck and happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
        
        $(".delet-btn").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".card").remove();
        });
```

```css
.card {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="collect">
        <div class="card">
            <button data-delete='1' class="delet-btn">Delete</button>
            CARD 1
            <select name="" id="" data-select='1'>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <button data-delete='2' class="delet-btn">Delete</button>
            CARD 2
            <select name="" id="" data-select='2'>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <button data-delete='3' class="delet-btn">Delete</button>
            CARD 3
            <select name="" id="" data-select='3'>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

for  your  Second question i  use  jquery to delete card.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there are MANY ways to achieve the same problem, I've done a simple snippet in **Plain JavaScript** to solve both problems you've...

```js
function changeOption (e) {
  alert("New Option is: " + e.target.value)
}
```

```css
.card {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="collect">
  <div class="card">
      <button onClick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Delete</button>
      CARD 1
      <select onChange="changeOption(event)" name="" id="">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <button onClick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Delete</button>
      CARD 2
      <select onChange="changeOption(event)" name="" id="">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <button onClick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">Delete</button>
      CARD 3
      <select onChange="changeOption(event)" name="" id="">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would be great.